# Kotlin, Gradle: mixing Android and non-Android modules

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm working in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 EAP. And when I add Android Gradle plug-in, output dirs of non-Android modules (project structure -> non-Android module -> paths) start pointing to `build/classes/java/main & test`, but actual classes are in `build/classes/kotlin/main & test`. As a result, I can't run JUnit tests (no tests found) or plain applications with `public static void main(String[])`.

https://github.com/Miha-x64/mixed-android-kotlin-project

What am I doing wrong? Or it is a bug?

Comment: did you ever get around this issue? I've had this problem for years and have been maintaining IntelliJ (non-gradle) project files for some time, with no luck. Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: I just run my tests from Gradle. No green ticks, no coverage. I don't even know how many tests I have in different modules. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122904